# Excute Procedure in Parallel or Async

Tags: .net, performance, sql-server, parallel-programming, asynchronous

I have inherited an application which performs approximately 100,000 executions in a C# for-loop against SQL Server.

```
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++)
{
  //Execution can take 0.250 to 5 seconds to complete.
  ExecuteProc(i); // no result returned
}
```

To reduce the time it takes to execute all 100,000 procedures, would it be better to:

1. convert this loop to a .Net parallel-foreach
   loop or
2. execute the procedure asynchronously ?

Answer (score 3):

It feels like you are trying to fix the wrong thing here.  Why do you even have 100,000 sprocs (or execute the same set of sprocs 100,000 times).  I bet this problem could be solved by simply writing some better SQL that doesn't require this kind of insanity.

Also... Parallel/asynchronous approaches are a bad idea if the order of execution matters.  If the order matters... You can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to push the loop into the database.

Driving the database externally to do the 100,000 operations in parallel will probably thrash the database, and it more than likely won't have the knowledge to fix it in any reasonable way, because it doesn't get a chance to see the larger problem.

If you can push the loop into the database, it will (1) minimize the round-trip overhead, and, (2) give the database a fighting chance at seeing the full size of the problem you're asking it to solve, so just might figure out a way to parallelize or use multiple threads on that larger problem.

(We don't know what `ExecuteProc` does but if we did, it is conceivable that you could eliminate the 100,000 runs with a different, maybe larger and more complex stored proc.)

Answer (score 1):

Is `ExecuteProc` an asynchronous call? if you're doing IO (and web requests are IO), then spawning a bajillion threads that each wait for a synchronous operation just risks tying up all the threads so they can't do useful work. they'll all just be sleeping until the call finishes.

If you have access to an asynchronous api, then the amount of threads isn't super important, because there is hardly any CPU work at all involved in sending a query to a SQL server.

If you only have a synchronous api, then paralellizing can speed things up but it will be much more resource intensive. try your options out and measure what suits you best. only you know what your limitations are.